# How to do query string query in Elasticsearch.Net?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

How can i convert this query to dot net:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "TEVA"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried :

```
    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<SearchEntity> {
                                  Query = new QueryStringQuery() {Query = "TEVA"}};
    (await _elastic.SearchAsync<SearchEntity>(searchRequest))
```

but i get zero result.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `TypedKeys = null` solve my problem.

```
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<SearchEntity>
        {
            Query = new QueryStringQuery()
            {
                Query = queryString
            },
            TypedKeys = null,
            Size = 100,
            MinScore = 8,
        };
        var searchResponse = (await
            _elastic.SearchAsync<SearchEntity>(searchRequest));
```